# A relation in a finitely generated module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $I$ is an ideal of $R$, and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module s.t. $M=IM$. How to prove:
>   $$\exists a \in I \text{ such that } (1-a)M=0. $$

I tried to solve:
$\exists a \in I $   s.t. $(1-a)M=0 $   i.e. $M=IM=aM$ i.e $M$ is cycle.$$(1M-aM=0 \rightarrow 1M=aM \rightarrow M=aM)$$

Comment: This is not enough. Did you hear about Nakayama's lemma ?

Comment: @DietrichBurde , how to use this lemma? [Nakayama's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama_lemma)

Comment: Read statement $1$ there carefully, and conclude that $r=1-a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Use your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952850/a-relation-involving-an-endomorphism-of-a-finitely-generated-module) with $\phi=1_M$.